# Dúvida erro de Syntax em função PHP / jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Estou consumindo um Webservice em um site de um cliente.
eu pego o retorno da url, filtro da forma que preciso, para exibir somente os campeonatos com a condição:

"SEXO : M "
"MODALIDADE : 2"
"CATEGORIA : 4"
Sendo todas verdadeiras, me retorna o nome do campeonato correto, só que está retornando o seguinte erro:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

**Na seguinte linha:**

`"var html = '<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#home" role="tab">'+<td>1ª Fase</td><td>CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE OURO</td>+'</a>';"`

já tentei escrever de outras formas, concatenar, e nada do erro sumir, por favor poderiam me ajudar?

**teste.php**

```
<?php 
$api_request = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=2HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL';
$api_response = wp_remote_get( $api_request );
$api_data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $api_response ), true );
$retorno = '';

if($api_data){
    foreach($api_data as $row){
        if(!is_array($row)){
            //$retorno = $retorno.'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
        }else{
            if($row['sexo'] == 'M' && $row['modalidade'] == 2 && $row['categoria'] == 4){
                $retorno = $retorno.'<td>'.$row['nome'].'</td>';
            }   
        }

    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(function(){
  
  var html = '<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#home" role="tab">'+<?php echo $retorno;?>+'</a>';
   
    $('#myList').html(html);
    
 });
```

Comment: Vc está criando o html errado, tem que ficar tudo dentro de apenas uma aspa simples **''**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto seria:

```
$(function(){

    var html = '<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#home" role="tab"><?php echo $retorno;?></a>';

    $('#myList').html(html);

});
```

Não precisa concatenar na string javascript pois o php atua no servidor e já renderiza o html direto ali.

Comment: nossa, deu certo!, obrigado pela ajuda, não tenho muita experiência com esse tipo de função, eu gostaria que cada um dos campeonatos fosse exibido em uma div diferente, você poderia me explicar como fazer isso?

Comment: Posso tentar ajudar sim @MiguelCampos. Aconselho abrir uma outra pergunta, especificando melhor o seu problema, e lá eu tento respondê-lo novamente.

Comment: certo, muito obrigado!